# I've a wordpress website running running nginx + php7-fpm. Wordpress url redirection

Tags: nginx, php, redirect, php-fpm, wordpress

My clients wordpress websites is serving many 404 requests. After checking I could see that the 404 URLs are like

```
/wp-content/uploads/2015/8/a.png&_nc_hash=ASsvdeeknbhs
```

and it throws 404 error. But if we add a '?' after that filename, it will show the content. the working url was like

```
/wp-content/uploads/2015/8/a.png?&_nc_hash=ASsvdeeknbhs
```

How to set this redirection in nginx ? Please help me to achieve above redirection.
Any good recommendations would be appreciated.

Comment: You should find out which part of the website generates these invalid URLs in the first place. Adding a redirect to fix this issue makes it simply more complicated.

Comment: Thank you.  I have been looking for a temporary/immediate fix.

Answer (score 0):

I have been looking for a temporary/immediate fix. The following redirection rules helped me.

```
rewrite ^(.*)&_nc_eui2(.*)$ $1?&_nc_eui2$2 permanent;
rewrite ^(.*)&_nc_hash(.*)$ $1?&_nc_hash$2 permanent;
rewrite ^(.*)word(.*)$ $1newwordOLDWORD$2 permanent;
```

I hope it would help someone. :)